# Is it distracting to display fields over a fullscreen image background?

Tags: login, background-images

I was somewhat inspired by the Twitter login page, which has a nice "fullscreen" background picture on the login page. Here is what I did for my webserver:

[image]

Is using a fullscreen background with translucent input fields distracting or inappropriate? Are the input fields clear enough? How would usability be improved here?

Comment: Are you asking about this particular image / input field combination, or just background images showing behind fields in general?

Comment: This one in particular, although general considerations are also welcome.

Comment: We can't do reviews for individual sites / apps so I have made the question more generic so it serves more use to other people. If you want specific reviews of your examples then StackExchange isn't really the place for that. (perhaps it'd be OK in Chat maybe, but not the main question site)

Comment: I get your question but maybe you might consider how this question could be edited in order to be applicable to more than just your site's specific login screen - the question seems to be about *this type of login screen*, so maybe you can redirect discussion to that.

Comment: In this specific case, the contrast isn't high enough, hover in the bing example (in one of the answers) the contrast is much better (yet still needs improving).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you should be fine. The reason being the  login box is subtle enough to blend with the background design but also stands out due to its color scheme . The login call to action due to its deep blue color also works well against the lighter blue of the aurora borealis since its distinctive enough.However if you are going to constantly change your background image be careful that your form elements dont get lost against the login page background.

[Bing](http://www.bing.com/) overcomes this by ensuring there is significant contrast between the background image and the front text (and logo) as shown below:

[image]

I recommend looking at this link *[10 colour contrast checking tools to improve the accessibility of your design](http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/200709/10_colour_contrast_checking_tools_to_improve_the_accessibility_of_your_design/)* for some tools which can help you determine how your background text stands out against your image (You will have to use a color picker to determine the background color since none  of the tools support images) since I am unable to make out if the contrast is sufficient for them.

Comment: Seconded. The contrast doesn't look sufficient to me, so worth checking

Answer (score 1):

It's nice, but I'm not sure there's enough focus on the input form. Try increasing the opacity of the form or reducing the luminosity of the image (the bright green stream is too potent in your current design).

Increasing the opacity of the form will also improve the readability of your field placeholder text.

Answer (score 0):

It is quite clear and it doesn't distract. In fact, you can use this background image for not just branding purpose but also

-- show some new updates to your websites

-- tell some good statistics about your website

-- show promotion videos or images